# Using Index/Match with an array and multiple match types

Tags: excel-formula

Maybe I'm going about it all wrong so I'm open to all suggestions.

I am trying to assign a grade (A-F) to a row based on a percentage.  The criteria is as follows:

```
 A = 0
 B = +/-2
 C = +/-15 (between 2 and 15 %)
 D = +/-25 (between 15 and 25 %)
 F = +/-26 or more

| **Percent Remaining** | **Grade** |
| :-------------------: | :-------: |
| 0.00%                 |A    
| -1.77%                |B    
| 5.5%                  |C    
| -18.53%               |D    
| 27.4%                 |F
```

So these are percentages of budgets spent so the criteria needs to be positive or negative so, for example overspending by 1.77 percent would have return a value of -1.77% and a "B" grade would need to be assigned or under spending returns a positive number which should yield the same results. I don't know why the markdown tips are not working for me for tables.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a lookup table with the Absolute thresholds and the corresponding result.

Then use VLOOKUP on the Absolute of the value:

```
=VLOOKUP(ABS(A1),C:D,2,TRUE)
```

[image]

Or you can use a hard coded INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX({"A","B","C","D","F"},MATCH(ABS(A1),{0,.0001,.0201,.1501,.2501}))
```

Comment: Well I need the percentage ranges to return a grade.  What you suggest won't work for that if I understand correctly.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you just need to set the lower limit of the grade so B would be `.0001` which is `.01%`.  You need to decided to what precision you want and set that as the lower limit.

Comment: I tried to edit to show a new picture but it did not let me, so I put in C1:C5: `0`,`.0001`,`.0201`,`.1501`,`.2501` respectively and then it will find the percentage.  This is to the hundredth percent precision.

Comment: Thank you so much the index/match worked!  I guess I just don't understand what the ABS does